# Migration From RDBMS To Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sybase, rdbms, datastax

I need to migrate 5 TB of Image data from RDBMS to cassandra. I have tried sqoop but it is too slow. Can anyone please suggest any tool for migration.

Thanks

Comment: An off topic recommendation question. Also Unclear What you are Asking (why is it too slow?).

Answer (score 0):

Use spark for large data moves between systems.
It is distributed and resilient.

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver",
  "dbtable" -> "schema.tablename"))
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

```
jdbcDF.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
            options(keyspace="ks", table="tablename").\
            save(mode="append")
```

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md

You can use open source Apache Spark or DataStax Enterprise.
Datastax Enterprise provides Apache Cassandra + Apache Spark + many other stuff installed on each nodes for perfect distributed processing and data locality between Spark and Cassandra.
I'm a DataStax employee.